# Regex: Only capture if there is (are) characters between the searched characters

Tags: regex

In my `LaTeX` work I need to do Regex search with `\|(.*?)\|` to capture `|whatever|` and replace it with `\somecommand{$1}`. But I do not want to capture `||` (That is, there is nothing between them.) How should I refine my regex search?

(By the way, what should my title be, so that it is useful for others?)

Comment: `\|(.+)\|` this only matches if you have one or more characters inside the pipes. But this will also match other pipes in between pipes, so it would probably be better to exclude any pipes from the match: `\|[^|]+\|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the asterix (which matches 0+ times) to a plus sign make the quantifier match at least 1 character.

```
\|(.+?)\|
    ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to,

```
\|[^|]+\|
```

OR

```
\|.+\|
```

If you want to also capture pipes in between searched content